# Java unable to parse nested json object

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

Below is some sample code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

String k = "{\"root1\":\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"val1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":1,\\\"key3\\\":null}\",\"root2\":\"OTHERS\",\"root3\":1}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
System.out.println(obj);

/* 
here I want to do something like:
JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("root1");
String k1 = innerObj.get("key1");

Also, should work with nested inner objects, so for example, should be able to do:
String k4 = innerObj.get("key1.innerKey1");
*/
```

```
{"root1":"{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":1,\"key3\":null}","root2":"OTHERS","root3":1}
```

On doing JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("root1"); - it gives:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

I tried Gson, JSONParser - but still unable to do it ...

Note: Parsing of string 'k' works fine, as the obj is populated correctly and is printed out. It fails when I try to access objects within this obj:
JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("root1");

Comment: The `root1` key maps to a string. That's what the `\"` quotes are doing inside your JSON. It looks like your JSON was put together wrong.

Comment: Your `root1` property is not a JSON object; it is _a string whose value is JSON_, whose root value is a JSON object. Correct the assembly if _at all_ possible; if not, you'll need to extract the string and run it through parsing a second time.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- - hw to do that ?
i am using import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 1):

There is utility [StringEscapeUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) in apache commons text library for such translations. Applying it will remove those extra double quotes around `root1` value.

Add this [commons-text](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.9) jar dependency to your project.

Usage -

```
String k = "{\"root1\":\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"val1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":1,\\\"key3\\\":null}\",\"root2\":\"OTHERS\",\"root3\":1}";

// add this line
String unescapedJsonString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(k);

 // pass new json string to Json library
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(unescapedJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String k ="{\"root1\":{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":1,\"key3\":null},\"root2\":\"OTHERS\",\"root3\":1}";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(k);
    System.out.println(obj);
     
    //here I want to do something like:
    JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("root1");
    Object k1 =  innerObj.get("key1");
    System.out.println(k1);
    Object k2 =  innerObj.get("key2");
    System.out.println(k2);
    Object k3 =  innerObj.get("key3");
    System.out.println(k3);
    
    System.out.println(obj.get("root2"));
    System.out.println(obj.get("root3"));
}
```

Output -

```
{"root1":{"key1":"val1","key2":1,"key3":null},"root2":"OTHERS","root3":1}
val1
1
null
OTHERS
1
```

Comment: not sure who down voted it ... 

i did similar thing in my actual code, but when i access inner element and then print it, it gives something like:

```
JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("root1");
logger.debug("inner obj: " + innerObj.toString());
```

inner obj: {"bytes":[123,34,101],"empty":false}

Comment: and my problem is as stated by @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- above : 

'Your root1 property is not a JSON object; it is a string whose value is JSON, whose root value is a JSON object. Correct the assembly if at all possible; if not, you'll need to extract the string and run it through parsing a second time.'

yes, so value of my root1 is a string with JSONObj - not a JSONObj